# Keep / Exclude brushed data in parallel coordinates d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7586334) and trying to give it the same functionality for keeping/excluding the information in the brush as [this example by Kai](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3150059).

I have reviewed the code and apparently, Kai's example is built upon V.2 of D3 (at least the script that it calls is there). Because of this most of the coordinate system is not based upon the d3.parcoords.js library. My question is, how would I be able get the same result using parcoords.js ? Do you think it will be needed to modify parcoords.js to include Kai's functionality? I think that the problem is that the method Kai uses conflicts with the parcoords.js methods to draw axes.

I reviewed the parcoords.js documentation and there are no indications of a method or function to extract this information, at least in the same way. I am fairly new to javascript, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The part of the code I am trying to port is at the very bottom.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Decision making tool</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_/d3%20library/d3.parcoords.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_/d3%20library/style.css">
<style>
    /* data table styles */

    #grid {
        height: 198px;
    }

    .row,
    .header {
        clear: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    .row:nth-child(odd) {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    .header {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .cell {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    .col-0 {
        width: 180px;
    }
</style>

<script src="_/d3 library/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="_/d3 library/d3.parcoords.js"></script>
<script src="_/d3 library/divgrid.js"></script>
<script src="_/script.js"></script>

//The header div includes the buttons that are shown below.
<div id="header">
    <h1>EUI assesment tool</h1>
    <button title="Zoom in on selected data" id="keep-data" disabled="disabled">Keep</button>
    <button title="Remove selected data" id="exclude-data" disabled="disabled">Exclude</button>
</div>
<div id="chart" class="parcoords" style="height:600px;"></div>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="brushing">
    // quantitative color scale

    var green_to_red = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([40, 200])
        .range(["green", "red"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab);

    var color = function(d) {
        return green_to_red(d['Site EUI (kBtu/sq ft)']);
    };


    var parcoords = d3.parcoords()("#chart")
        .color(color)
        .margin({
            top: 50,
            left: 250,
            bottom: 20,
            right: 20
        })
        //  .composite('lighter')
        .alpha(0.25);

    // load csv file and create the chart
    d3.csv('_/data/Mock Data Chicago.csv', function(data) {
        parcoords
            .data(data)
            .hideAxis(["Property Name", "Address", "Community Area", "ZIP Code", "# of Buildings", "ENERGY STAR Score"])
            .mode("queue")
            .rate(30)
            .interactive()
            .render()
            .brushMode("1D-axes"); // enable brushing

        // create data table, row hover highlighting
        var grid = d3.divgrid();
        d3.select("#grid")
            .datum(data.slice(0, 5))
            .call(grid)
            .selectAll(".row")
            .on({
                "mouseover": function(d) {
                    parcoords.highlight([d])
                },
                "mouseout": parcoords.unhighlight
            });

        // update data table on brush event
        parcoords.on("brush", function(d) {
            d3.select("#grid")
                .datum(d.slice(0, 5))
                .call(grid)
                .selectAll(".row")
                .on({
                    "mouseover": function(d) {
                        parcoords.highlight([d])
                    },
                    "mouseout": parcoords.unhighlight
                });
        });
    });
//Below is the code I copied from Kai's version. I think the if statement is not returning information for the buttons above to enable
    if (selected.length < data.length && selected.length > 0) {
        d3.select("#keep-data").attr("disabled", null);
        d3.select("#exclude-data").attr("disabled", null);
    } else {
        d3.select("#keep-data").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        d3.select("#exclude-data").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    };

    function keep_data() {
        new_data = actives();
        if (new_data.length == 0) {
            alert("I don't mean to be rude, but I can't let you remove all the data.\n\nTry removing some brushes to get your data back. Then click 'Keep' when you've selected data you want to look closer at.");
            return false;
        }
        data = new_data;
        rescale();
    }

    // Exclude selected from the dataset
    function exclude_data() {
        new_data = _.difference(data, actives());
        if (new_data.length == 0) {
            alert("I don't mean to be rude, but I can't let you remove all the data.\n\nTry selecting just a few data points then clicking 'Exclude'.");
            return false;
        }
        data = new_data;
        rescale();
    }
</script>
```

It may be something with the if statement not getting information?

Comment: It would be best if you add that code here.

Comment: Hello @HanletEscaño thanks for the tip. I updated my post.